# Tornado webserver and Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, tornado

I have been unsuccessful in trying to use ember.js with Tornado web server because both tornado template engine and ember use the handle bars (squiggly brackets) {{ and }} and when you try to use ember calls, tornado throws an error.

Is there a way to get this working without changing tornado or ember own source code ?

I am fine with disabling the tornado template, I don't need to use it although the {% extend is nice, I don't need it. It is very important that I can get this working without changing 3rd party tools.

But in the end, I would be ok with changing tornado if I need to.

I have tried to just read in the index file as a static file and then just print it out, but that has it's own issues, like all paths will be incorrect for css and javascript files, but that can be fixed.

But there surely is a config that can change the way the template works, or disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed in the documentation[1](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/template.html#syntax-reference) for the templating engine, if you mark the squiggly brackets like this;

`{{!view App.IndexView}}`

the Tornado templating engine will treat it as a literal `{{`, and pass it through, minus the exclamation mark;

`{{view App.IndexView}}`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about tornado, but Ember doesn't require templates to be in your index.html file. They can be compiled into JS functions using Ember.Handlebars.compile and set on Ember.TEMPLATES. e.g. `Ember.TEMPLATES['application'] = Ember.Handlebars.compile('Hello {{planet}}!');` An approach like that should let you avoid places that tornado will try to interpret your curlies.